# IOS/Objective-C: Case Insenstive Search using StringByReplacingOccurenceOfString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am confused about case insensitive search of an NSString.

I gather a regular `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is always case sensitive:

```
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:verb withString:@" "];
```

but there is a variant `stringByReplacingOccurencesofString options: range:` that has a case insensitive option.

```
  - (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement 
                                           options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options 
                                             range:(NSRange)searchRange;
```

I got an error when I tried to specify range: nil.  What does the range refer to and how do I know what range to specify, X Y in the example above if I don't know whether the searchstring will be found?

Thanks in advance for any insights and suggestions.

Comment: Range parameter is not an object type, hence the error with nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in the range of the entire string if you don't have a specific range your are looking for. To get the whole range of the string, you can use `[string rangeOfString:string]` or `NSMakeRange(0, string.length)`.

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringToReplace 
                           withString:replacementString 
                           options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                           range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```